# ¿En qué orden histórico llegaron los significados al vocablo "luego"?

Tags: historia, definiciones, adverbios, conjunciones

Recuerdo que cuando niño con 6 o 7 años, al oír o leer la frase de Descartes *Pienso, luego existo*, creí que exhortaban a la persona a que se dedicara a pensar... y que de momento no se preocupase por existir, que lo podría hacer después...
Ya luego vino la adolescencia, una que otra clase de Español y de Filosofía, y comprendí que el *luego* = *ergo* = *por tanto* o *es decir que* o... creo que ya me entendieron.
Pero recientemente me queda la duda si el *luego* empezó como adverbio temporal (*después*) o como conjunción ilativa (*por tanto*).

La etimología de [*luego*](https://dle.rae.es/luego) en el DLE no ayuda mucho:

> Del lat. vulg. loco, abl. de locus 'lugar'.

y el mapa de diccionarios en 1780 ya incluye ambas definiciones. ¿Cuál fue la primera definición que tuvo la palabra?

Comment: Consultando los textos más antiguos del CORDE y  diccionarios más antiguos mediante el Nuevo Tesoro Lexicológico puede Vd mismo profundizar en su búsqueda y solventar su duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, en el *Autoridades* aparecen estos tres significados:

- "Al instante". *Luego que tuve edad, aprendí a leer y escribir.*
- "Después". *Venía luego el Cardenal Diácono con otros tres gentiles hombres.*
- Para significar la conclusión de algún razonamiento. *Esto no puede ser, luego lo contrario es forzosa verdad.*

Hay que ir remontando hacia atrás. Por ejemplo, en el *Percival* de 1591 aparece *luego* traducido al inglés como:

- By and by (equivalente a "tras un corto periodo de tiempo").
- Then.
- Therefore (usado para las conclusiones de razonamientos).

Lo mismo ocurre con el *Casas* de 1570, que traduce *luego* como "dùnque", usado también para las conclusiones de razonamientos. Y llegamos al *Nebrija* de 1495, que incluye tres acepciones de *luego*:

- *Ilico*, que en latín sería "al momento", "al instante", "en el mismo lugar".
- *Continuo*, que según veo lleva el sentido de conexión de una cosa con otra, ya sea en espacio o en tiempo, y que según el Lewis & Short lleva también la connotación de consecuencia lógica (aunque los autores reconocen no estar seguros).
- *Cum primum*, pero esta es referente a la expresión *luego que*, más en el sentido de "después de".

Entiendo pues que en el *Nebrija* puedo tenerse también en cuenta el significado de *luego* como consecuencia lógica. Lo suyo entonces es irse a textos antiguos. En el CORDE aparecen miles de casos de *luego*, lo que hace que la búsqueda sea un poco complicada. Restringiendo la búsqueda a textos anteriores a 1200 aparecen 55 casos en 7 documentos, y todos parecen ser de la acepción de "después" (ya sea inmediatamente después o no):

> *Besóle la mano, el espada tomó e recibió; luego se levantó mio Cid el Campeador.*

Si nos vamos al siglo XIII los casos son ya demasiados como para examinarlos uno a uno, mas lo que estoy viendo es que prácticamente todos los casos siguen siendo usos de *luego* como "después". Y lo mismo con los del siglo XIV. No es hasta el siglo XV que por fin encuentro algún que otro uso de *luego* (pocos, en realidad) como consecuencia lógica:

> *Y pues el salimiento del Saluador que todos esperamos dize el profeta que será de los antes de los syglos de los días del siglo, claro está que antes de los syglos de los días del syglo non ay sinon Dios, luego él es Dios.*
>
> Anónimo, "Historia de los Reyes Magos", c 1490 (España).